# Different TextView Sizes for different devices

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to display different text view sizes depending on the device (smartphone, 7" tablet, 10" tablet) on Android, any ideas?

Comment: Please take a look at the Android documentation. Especially around 'Supporting Multiple Screens'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly put this in your layout

```
textSize="@dimen/text_size"
```

and make dimen.xml in following folders in res directory

```
values
values-hdpi
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-sw1024dp-land
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp-land
```

and according to your need change the value of the size in these different dimes.xml

Comment: @Ana, it allright, you have started learning and half of you job is done :)